# Short + Frequent or Long + Rare swims?

Tags: workout-routines, swimming

I go to the pool nearly everyday, and I swim laps (25y lengths, 50y laps). I noticed that swimming 10-12 laps (250-300y) doesn't really tire me out, so I can do it daily. But, swimming a mile (33 laps, 1650y) does tire me out, so much so that I need to rest for a couple days (1-2). The two patterns (~11/day and ~33/ 3 days) have the same daily lap average. Which is better for me? 11 laps per day, or 33 laps one day with a 2 day break?

My guess was (Because it takes about 3-4 days for the microtears in muscles to rebuild) that the 33 laps is better than the 11.

Comment: Are you swimming 10-12 laps (500-600y) or lengths (250-300)?  And what do you mean by better?  Better for what purpose?

Comment: 10-12 laps. Better for the purpose of gaining muscle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A combination would be best. Swim 11 laps 4-5 days a week (consider doing 20 or so laps one of those days), and then one day a week swim 33 laps.

Every day that you skip swimming, you lose the feel of the water and your strength and stamina begin to decrease. At the same time, you won't ever get better without pushing yourself, so swimming distance 1 day a week will help with that.

Comment: Can you explain the reasoning behind your answer?  What do you base it on?

Comment: So would you agree with this pattern: Day 1: 11, Day 2: 20, Day 3: 11, Day 4: 11, Day 5: 33, then repeat?

Comment: I think that is good, or: Day 1: 11, Day 2: 11, Day 3: 20, Day 4: 11, Day 5:11, Day 6: 33.

Answer (score 0):

Go with 33 laps per day with rests and in a month you'll be able to do that (or even more) every day. Swimming is a physical activity - you get better at it by training.